# How to change the text-flow direction of CSS multi-column paragraphs from "horizontal" to "vertical"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-multicolumn-layout

Given: a clean page with one `<article>` containing some `<p>` paragraphs and a full width `<img>`.

I want the css multi-columns to flow not as in A, but as in B sothat the paragraphs flow from top-to-bottom and then from left-to-right. The `<img>` should stop this flowing and fill up the full article width. After that several more paragraphs again in the same fashion as B until the end of the same `<article>`.

At the moment, all works, except that the columns flow as in A, not as in B. What smart rule(s) have I overlooked in CSS?

- I don't want to touch the *clean* HTML here. No extra elements, classes, or ids.
- Adding only CSS for selecting and styling the current existing elements: `article`, `p`, `img`
- Only one `<article>.....</article>` element, so no article splitting before-and-after img!

---

[image]

---

[image]

```css
article p{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap: 24px;
    -moz-column-gap: 24px;
   column-gap: 24px;

 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;

 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 letter-spacing:-0.7px;
 word-spacing: -0.7px;
 color: #000;
}

article p:nth-of-type(n+2) {
 text-indent: 2em;
 margin-top: 20px;
}


img{
 width:500px;
 height:auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>

<p>Ventilatie is noodzakelijk voor een gezond binnenklimaat in ruimten waar mensen verblijven en gebeurt door koolzuurgas, vocht en verontreiniging af te voeren en verse lucht aan te voeren. De luchtverontreiniging kan van verschillende aard zijn (bijvoorbeeld sigarettenrook, bacteriën en schimmelsporen, chemische stoffen, stof, geurstoffen).</p>

<p>De noodzakelijke hoeveelheid te verversen lucht (debiet) hangt af van de productie van vocht, koolstofdioxide (CO²) en verontreiniging en de aard van de verontreiniging, en van het aantal mensen die in die ruimten verblijven. Spuiventilatie of luchten is niet hetzelfde als de hier genoemde ventilatie, maar heeft ten doel in korte tijd sterk verontreinigde binnenlucht af te voeren of te spuien. Dit kan worden bereikt door ramen en/of deuren tegen elkaar open te zetten.</p>

<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg" alt=""/>

<p>Bij de meeste woningen gebeurt de ventilatie ongecontroleerd: doordat de wind in kieren en spleten waait, ververst de lucht. Dit zorgt in vele gevallen voor overbodige ventilatie, een onaangenaam binnenklimaat en dus ook voor warmteverliezen.</p>

<p>Men kan dit verminderen door tijdens het bouwen en onderhoud aandacht te besteden aan luchtdichtheid. Meestal wordt daarvoor een dampscherm geplaatst tegen de isolatie. Men dient rekening te houden met de vochthuishouding: als de warme vochtige binnenlucht kan doordringen tot in de isolatie zal deze lucht afkoelen naarmate de buitenmuur benaderd wordt, waardoor er condensatie kan optreden die de isolatiewaarde weer doet verminderen en is een dampdichte laag nodig om het damptransport te verminderen. Om dit makkelijker te onthouden zijn de dampremmende folies meestal rood (warm; binnenkant) en de damp-open folies blauw.</p>

<p>Ventilatie is noodzakelijk voor een gezond binnenklimaat in ruimten waar mensen verblijven en gebeurt door koolzuurgas, vocht en verontreiniging af te voeren en verse lucht aan te voeren. De luchtverontreiniging kan van verschillende aard zijn (bijvoorbeeld sigarettenrook, bacteriën en schimmelsporen, chemische stoffen, stof, geurstoffen).</p>

</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give the columns property to your container, not to your paragraphs...

That's for the text flow... Now, if you want inside the article to give your image 100% of the width container... well, you can't without changing html

```css
article {
text-align: justify;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap: 24px;
    -moz-column-gap: 24px;
   column-gap: 24px;

 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
}

article p{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0;
 

 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 letter-spacing:-0.7px;
 word-spacing: -0.7px;
 color: #000;
}

article p:nth-of-type(n+2) {
 text-indent: 2em;
 margin-top: 20px;
}


img{
 width:500px;
 height:auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>

<p>Ventilatie is noodzakelijk voor een gezond binnenklimaat in ruimten waar mensen verblijven en gebeurt door koolzuurgas, vocht en verontreiniging af te voeren en verse lucht aan te voeren. De luchtverontreiniging kan van verschillende aard zijn (bijvoorbeeld sigarettenrook, bacteriën en schimmelsporen, chemische stoffen, stof, geurstoffen).</p>

<p>De noodzakelijke hoeveelheid te verversen lucht (debiet) hangt af van de productie van vocht, koolstofdioxide (CO²) en verontreiniging en de aard van de verontreiniging, en van het aantal mensen die in die ruimten verblijven. Spuiventilatie of luchten is niet hetzelfde als de hier genoemde ventilatie, maar heeft ten doel in korte tijd sterk verontreinigde binnenlucht af te voeren of te spuien. Dit kan worden bereikt door ramen en/of deuren tegen elkaar open te zetten.</p>

<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg" alt=""/>

<p>Bij de meeste woningen gebeurt de ventilatie ongecontroleerd: doordat de wind in kieren en spleten waait, ververst de lucht. Dit zorgt in vele gevallen voor overbodige ventilatie, een onaangenaam binnenklimaat en dus ook voor warmteverliezen.</p>

<p>Men kan dit verminderen door tijdens het bouwen en onderhoud aandacht te besteden aan luchtdichtheid. Meestal wordt daarvoor een dampscherm geplaatst tegen de isolatie. Men dient rekening te houden met de vochthuishouding: als de warme vochtige binnenlucht kan doordringen tot in de isolatie zal deze lucht afkoelen naarmate de buitenmuur benaderd wordt, waardoor er condensatie kan optreden die de isolatiewaarde weer doet verminderen en is een dampdichte laag nodig om het damptransport te verminderen. Om dit makkelijker te onthouden zijn de dampremmende folies meestal rood (warm; binnenkant) en de damp-open folies blauw.</p>

<p>Ventilatie is noodzakelijk voor een gezond binnenklimaat in ruimten waar mensen verblijven en gebeurt door koolzuurgas, vocht en verontreiniging af te voeren en verse lucht aan te voeren. De luchtverontreiniging kan van verschillende aard zijn (bijvoorbeeld sigarettenrook, bacteriën en schimmelsporen, chemische stoffen, stof, geurstoffen).</p>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured that out (that the colums flow correctly if I gave the whole article the column span not the p elements). For now lets suppose that you are right and that its IMPOSSIBLE with CSS and we need to alter the HTML for the image going 100%, then how to solve the last problem? "if you want inside the article to give your image 100% of the width container." Please make the imge flow 100% in your code snippet. Please respect the other rules: only 1 article element and no other elements except for the <img> in html/css. Awaiting your response for this puzzle :-)